# XPrinter XP58-IIH printer cutting issue

Tags: java, printing

I got a 58mm POS XPrinter 58-IIH. It work fine with some ESC/POS commands not all of them though. The printer has a cutter, but i have not been able to get it to cut. I have printed some stuff with my java program, a lot of stuff really, but I have not been able to get the paper cutter to work.

I have tried using the following POS commands

```
{27,105},
{27,109},
{27,121},
{27,12},
{27,118},
{27,100,48)
{29,86,48,0},
{29,86,66}
```

I have tried searching but cant get any more codes to try. Please can someone help me with a solution. The mode of connection to pc is via USB cable, and I installed the drivers for the printer from Xprinter website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I found out that XPrinter 58-IIH does not support auto cutter feature. I decided to post this in case anyone runs into this trouble and could find this useful...